# Fast elasticsearch CASE WHEN THEN ELSE equivalent?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to build an exclusive bucketing aggregation in Elasticsearch (ie. the documents are assigned to the FIRST bucket to meet the criterion, not ALL buckets that meet it as the filters might overlap - this is the same behavior as a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE in SQL environments). Currently I am using a [Filters Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation) coupled with a [Bool Query/Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to achieve what I want. The idea is to use the "must" and "must_not" parts of the "Bool Query" where the "must" is my filter and the "must_not" is the collection of all the other filters that have already been used previously. An example would be:

```
GET _search
{
    "query":{"match_all":{}},
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "bin_1": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": { <filter1> },
                    "must_not": { <empty> }
                }
            }
        },
        "bin_2": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": { <filter2> },
                    "must_not": { <filter1> }
                }
            }
        },
        "bin_3": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": { <filter3> },
                    "must_not": { <filter1>, <filter2> }
                }
            }
        },
        "bin_else": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": { <empty> },
                    "must_not": { <filter1>, <filter2>, <filter3> }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a relational approach, the same would be achieved by the CASE WHEN clause like so:

```
CASE WHEN <filter1> THEN <bin_1>
     WHEN <filter2> THEN <bin_2>
     WHEN <filter3> THEN <bin_3>
     ELSE <bin_else>
END
```

The problem with this approach is that it gets slower and slower the more buckets I add (in my real case I even have nested buckets). Is there any language support for exclusive bucketing like this in Elastic? Or any other faster approach that would yield the same results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution would be to Script fields. It would use the if else logic, so no extra conditions would be used. Just I do not know what kind of filter you are using but it should be possible to implement anything I think. I will write here an equivalent of

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN <filter1> THEN <bin_1>
     WHEN <filter2> THEN <bin_2>
     ELSE <bin_else>
END as binning
FROM SOMETHING
```

Implemented using script fields in painless language. As is described here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html
and painless here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/5.6/painless-examples.html

```
GET _search
{
"query" : { "match_all": {} },
"script fields" : {
    "binning" : {
        "script" : {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "if (<filter>) {return <bin1>;} else if (<filter2>) {return <bin2>;} else {return <bin3>;}"
        }
    }
}
```

where the "filter" would be something like: doc['my_field'].value == "value1" where 'my_field' is the field that you use in the filter.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using scripted fields! Awesome idea, thank you @Honza. Do you have any idea about performance though? I suspect scripted fields are quite expensive in comparison to normal `bool` filters.